# Calendar getFirstDayOfWeek to Sunday

Tags: android, calendar, android-calendar

`Calendar.getFirstDayOfWeek()` returns the first day of the week, but it's a Monday. How can I make Sunday the first day? I tried to `Calendar.Day_of_week` to sunday first before getfirstday, but it went terribly wrong because I just found out that these are constants.

So again, problem is that how can I set first day to sunday so that i can get the first day of the week as a sunday? TIA

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You get Sunday as the default response if you are in US locale. But still if you want to set it manually to a particular day you can set it by using `setFirstDayOfWeek()` of Calendar. You can pass SUNDAY to it.

For Example

```
Calendar myCalendar = Calendar.getInstance();

myCalendar.setTime(new Date());  

myCalendar.setFirstDayOfWeek(Calendar.MONDAY);
```